# Override php.ini configuration from vhost or .htaccess

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I want a single specific vhost in my Apache configuration to override `auto_prepend` PHP configuration directive and always include a PHP file, without other sites including it.

One option is to use `SetEnv` in Apache and `getenv` in PHP with `auto_prepend` set in php.ini

Comment: depending on your config. u should be able to put a php.ini file in your vhost directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I'd try adding

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /your/path/here.php
```

to your vhost config. According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php), this method only works if PHP is run as an Apache *module*.